# Jupiter Notebook not showing titles or axis labels in marplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm running the following code in the latest version of Jupiter notebook.

```
x = list(np.linspace(25,55,6))
y = np.random.randint(10000,50000,6)

plt.xlabel = "some random ages"
plt.ylabel = 'some random salaries'
plt.title = 'whatever'

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

However the output does not have any labels or title. I know this question has been asked before but the solution that worked there, of putting everything in the same cell, is not working with me. I am running this in the same cell. Another suggestion from that question, of putting `put.show()` last, is also not working.

Comment: Use `plt.xlabel("some random ages")` instead of `plt.xlabel = "some random ages"` and so on for all three statements.

Comment: This gives : ```TypeError: 'str' object is not callable``` and its this very command that is being highlighted for the error.

Comment: I saw something on another similar question, and after restarting the kernel ```plt.xlabel("some random ages")``` works. Thanks.

Comment: See [Why do I get 'str' object is not callable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65172029/why-do-i-get-str-object-is-not-callable). This is happening because you have just overwritten all three functions with your statements `plt.xlabel = ""` etc, and turned them into "str" objects by doing so. Restarting your kernel without those statements should do it.